# How do I add and remove an event listener using a function with event argument and parameters?

Tags: javascript, typescript

For example, I have below function to execute when `mouseup` event occurs.

```
const listener = (element: HTMLElement, e: MouseEvent): void => {
    if (e.target instanceof Element && element && !element.contains(e.target)) {
        element.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
}
```

Then I am trying to figure out how to add extra paramter `element` to `listener` and remove it when it is not required anymore.

```
function addEventListener (element: HTMLElement) => {
    window.document.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => listener(element, e));
}

function removeEventListener (element: HTMLElement) => {
    window.document.removeEventListener('mouseup', ?? );
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

I tried using bind like below, but `MouseEvent` cannot bind before `addEventListener`.

```
let callback;

function addEventListener (element: HTMLElement) => {
    // how can I bind `MouseEvent`?
    callback = listener.bind(this, element, ??);
    window.document.addEventListener('mouseup', callback);
}

function removeEventListener (element: HTMLElement) => {
    window.document.removeEventListener('mouseup', callback);
}
```

Should I use closure here like below?

```
function createListener(element: HTMLElement) {
    return (e: MouseEvent) => {
        listener(element, e);
    }
}

let callback;

function addEventListener (element: HTMLElement) {
    callback = createListener(account);
    window.document.addEventListener('mouseup', callback);
}

function removeEventListener (element: HTMLElement) => {
    window.document.removeEventListener('mouseup', callback);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way you remove an event listener normally, but store a Map (dictionary) that maps an HTMLElement to a function:

```js
const callbacks = new Map<HTMLElement, (e: MouseEvent) => void>();

function addEventListener (element: HTMLElement) => {
    const callback = (e) => listener(element, e);
    callbacks.set(element, callback);
    window.document.addEventListener('mouseup', callback);
}

function removeEventListener (element: HTMLElement) => {
    const callback = callbacks.get(element);
    if(callback)
    {
        window.document.removeEventListener('mouseup', callback);
        delete callback;
    }
}
```

Comment: Typescript complains `TS7005: Variable 'callback' implicitly has an 'any' type`. I use `noImplicityAny: ture` option for type safety. What type should I use at `let callback`? I am guessing `let callback : (e: MouseEvent) => void;`.

Comment: @ibocon I've updated the answer

Comment: `TS2538: Type 'HTMLElement' cannot be used as an index type.` I will find a way to store callback functions and find it by element. After that, maybe I could update your answer.

Comment: @ibocon thanks for updating the answer. I'm assuming it works since you updated it yourself. It's strange that TypeScript was mad about using an HTMLElement as an index for a JS object, but it's fine when you use a Map (which is just a wrapper for a normal object with some extra functionality [which, i guess, is what every object is])